# RAILS: How to set collection_check_boxes value from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_tag where I am creating multiple checkboxes per field. I can get this to work and save the correct data to the database. My questions is: Is there a way to add the checked value if it has already been checked in the database like you can do with single checkboxes?

```
<%= form_tag ceremony_create_nominees_path(ceremony) do %>
    <% ceremony.awards.each_with_index do |award, i| %>
      <%= fields_for "award_#{i}" do |g| %>
         <%= g.hidden_field :award_id, value: award.id %>
         <%= g.collection_check_boxes :nominee_id, ceremony.invites, :id, :fullname %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I managed to get it to work with single checkboxes but then it would make the code to save it break.

What I was trying to do with the collection_check_boxes was along these lines but can't seem to find the id on the particular check box that it is on (nominee.id) which are in award.nominees:

```
<%= g.collection_check_boxes :nominee_id, ceremony.invites, :id, :fullname, {selected: Nominee.find_by(award_id: award.id, invite_id: nominee.id)}%>
```

Hope that made sense and any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I have also tried things like: 

`<%= g.collection_check_boxes :nominee_id, ceremony.invites, :id, :fullname, { checked: award.nominees.map(&:id) } %>`

Answer (score 0):

based on [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes):

it should get default value from the property name:

```
collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial)
```

If @post.author_ids is already `[1]`, this would return:

```
<input id="post_author_ids_1" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
...
```

as you can see the resulted HTML has `checked="checked"`